# save images in cache seperatly android

Tags: android, performance

I try to load images into carousel view. these images are downloaded from internet. We use three image url to download the images. I want to save these three images in separate three folders in cache. I did the following way. But all three images are save in one folder in cache.So I can't access these three images seperatly after save them cache.

Here my ImageLoader cache........

```
public class ImageLoader {

    private static final String TAG = "ImageLoader";
    ProgressBar progressbar;
    LinearLayout layout;
    int widthScreen,heightScreen;
    MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService;
    Handler handler=new Handler();//handler to display images in UI thread
    int sample;
    Context context;

    public ImageLoader(Context context){
        this.context=context;
        fileCache=new FileCache(context);
        executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    }
    public ImageLoader(Context context,int i){
        this.context=context;
        //fileCache=new FileCache(context);
        //executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    } 

    final int stub_id=R.drawable.tnlrocks;

    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmapMemory=memoryCache.get(url);

           queuePhoto(url, imageView);

    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        File f=fileCache.getFile(url);


        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;

        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(300000000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(300000000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream inputstream=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream outputstream = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(inputstream, outputstream);
            outputstream.close();
            conn.disconnect();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Throwable ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           if(ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
               memoryCache.clear();
           return null;
        }
    }

   public void getDimension(int width,int height){
       widthScreen=width;
       heightScreen=height;

   }
    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            final int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 120000000; // 1.2MP

            BitmapFactory.Options scaleOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            scaleOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            FileInputStream stream1=new FileInputStream(f);
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1,null,scaleOptions);
            stream1.close();

         // find the correct scale value as a power of 2.
            int scale = 1;
            while (scaleOptions.outWidth / scale / 2 >= widthScreen
              && scaleOptions.outHeight / scale / 2 >= heightScreen) {
              scale *= 2;
            }

           Bitmap bitmap = null;
            if (scale > 1) {
               scale--;
                // scale to max possible inSampleSize that still yields an image
                // larger than target
               scaleOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
               scaleOptions.inSampleSize = scale;
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1, null, scaleOptions);


                int width=widthScreen;
                int height=heightScreen;

                double y=height;
                double x=width;


                Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, (int) x, 
                   (int) y, true);
                bitmap.recycle();
                bitmap = scaledBitmap;

                System.gc();
            } else {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1);
            }
            if((widthScreen>=450)&& (heightScreen>=750) ) {
                sample=1;
            }
            else{
                sample=2;
            }
            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options scalOption = new BitmapFactory.Options();
           // scalOption.inSampleSize=sample;
            FileInputStream stream2=new FileInputStream(f);
            Bitmap bitMap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, scalOption);
            Bitmap resizedbitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitMap, widthScreen/2, heightScreen/3, true);
            stream2.close();
            return resizedbitmap;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
            url=u; 
            imageView=i;
        }
    } 

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
            this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                String s=photoToLoad.url;
                if(s!=null){

                }
                Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
                handler.post(bd);
            }catch(Throwable th){
                th.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
        String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        //Bitmap icon=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.tnlrocks);
        //Bitmap resizedbitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon, widthScreen, heightScreen, true);

        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
        public void run()
        {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if(bitmap!=null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                //photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(icon);
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        //fileCache.clear();
    }
```

}

This is my FileCache class. Here I give the directory....

```
public class FileCache {

    private File cacheDir;

    public FileCache(Context context){
        //Find the dir to save cached images
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"TNLRadio/res/events");
        else
            cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
        if(!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
    }

    public File getFile(String url){
        //I identify images by hashcode. Not a perfect solution, good for the demo.
        String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
        //Another possible solution (thanks to grantland)
        //String filename = URLEncoder.encode(url);
        File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
        return f;

    }

    public void clear(){
        File[] files=cacheDir.listFiles();
        if(files==null)
            return;
        for(File f:files)
            f.delete();
    }
}
```

So how to save images seperately three directories in cache & access them....
pls help me...

Comment: Maybe look for UniversalImageLoader https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader